# Difference between two date in an human readable format

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

I have an object that rapresent the time difference between a date and now (I used Luxon):

```
{days: -0, hours: -15, minutes: -38, months: -0, seconds: -46.389, years: -0}
```

and I want to print that information in an human readable way. So, in this case:

```
difference is 15 h, 38 min, 46 s
```

So, I wouldn't consider numbers equals to 0 and the result should be sorted so years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds.
What is the smarter way to do that?

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you already have some code we could take a look at?

Comment: @Mathyn not really. But the only idea I have is to iterate the object in a way very stupid

Comment: Just use toString() methods on the attributes of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
function toReadable(obj) {
    var names = {
        days: "d", hours: 'h', minutes: 'min', months: 'm', seconds: 's', years: 'y'
    }
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, v) => {
        if(obj[v] != 0) acc.push(Math.abs(Math.ceil(obj[v])) + ' ' + names[v]);
        return acc;
    }, []).join(', ')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't guarantee order in an object, you can keep the order in an array and use some logic for the modified names, e.g.

```js
function formatPeriod(obj) {
  return ['years','months','days','hours','minutes','seconds'].reduce((acc, key) => {
    let v = parseInt(Math.abs(obj[key])); 
    if (v != 0) acc.push(v + ' ' + key.slice(0,key=='minutes'?3:1));
    return acc;
  }, []).join(', ');
}

// Example
var data = {days: -0, hours: -15, minutes: -38, months: -0, seconds: -46.389, years: -0};
console.log(formatPeriod(data));
```